# How to find if a second-hand iPhone is stolen after purchase?

Tags: iphone

I bought a used iPhone 4 with iOS 7 from a local shop. I am not sure as to how to be sure if it is not stolen. I was able to do a factory reset on the phone and use my own Apple ID to use the phone.

I tried going to iCloud to check if Find My iPhone was active on the device and I found out that it is activated but using my Apple ID only.

I know that I should do a proper verification before I bought it but I think it is too late now and nothing can be done about it other than checking next time I buy a used phone.

As proof of purchase the store owner wrote the Price on a Plain paper with his name and phone number and handed it to me.

Comment: If it allowed to factory restore and use your AppleID, it is not stolen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I've made a pretty substantial edit to your question to narrow the scope down to the essence of what you are asking. If you feel I have lost crucial information, feel free to edit further.

Comment: @Buscar Just because Activation Lock was not active does not mean that the device is not stolen—the previous user may not have set it up.

Comment: @grgarside then there is no registered previous owner, is there ? and there is no way to find that out now.

Comment: @Buscar That is the purpose of this question.

Comment: and as @grgarside pointed out, if it was not registered by previous owner then nobody can claim it anyway.

Comment: @grgarside thanks for the editing :) I would like to add one point which I forgot the phone was jail broken when I purchased it.I found out about it recently when I tried to jail break it after the factory reset was done.

Comment: @Buscar웃  does it mean that it is safe to use the phone and the a person might not come searching the phone claiming that it is his or hers? as they do not have a proof?

Comment: it means exactly that, it is 100% yours now.

Comment: Wow! it is a great relief to know that 
Thanks guys for the help:) feels great to know that

Comment: as for the store owner handing you a hand written proof of purchase, that is a proof enough.

Answer (score -1):

Restoring an iOS device will remove any record of a previous owner on the device.

If the device was purchased from an Apple Store, then Apple may have record of it being set up even if Find My iPhone. This also applies to other retailers, however I am not certain if this is possible.

Comment: The restoring is only possible if it was not activated before by the previous owner, or with owners permission. In any case it is a hypothetical debate if was stolen or legitimately restored with permission from previous owner. "second hand phone"

Comment: @Buscar Could you clarify what exactly is incorrect about my answer?

Comment: the question: How to find if a second-hand iPhone is stolen after purchase? was not answered. It was not purchased from Apple store but from second hand shop. It was not locked (activated) by previous owner or unlocked with owners permission.

Comment: @Buscar I am talking about the *original* owner purchasing it from an Apple Store. The Apple Store or other retailer may have record of the person who purchased the device.

Comment: That is correct, but has nothing to do with the question. Possibly the original owner sold it to the store and gave its permission to unlock it so it can be restored and the store owner issued a new proof of purchase. So how is it stolen?

Comment: @Buscar Person 1 purchases this device from an Apple Store but does not set up Find My iPhone. Person 2 steals this device from Person 1 and sells it to Person 3. Person 3 does not know that Person 2 has stolen the device and sells the device to Person 4 (OP). The device is still stolen property. Therefore, it may be possible to find out who Person 1 is by asking an Apple Store to check the IMEI/etc which is what my answer is describing.

Comment: Why don't you say so in the first place. You are recommending the OP goes to Apple Store and find out if the iPhone is reported as stolen using the IMEI. If it was stolen, than take legal action against the second hand store and report them to the authority for selling stolen goods.